# Tagging questions about plot titles

Tags: discussion, tags

How should I tag questions about plot titles? For example, some of [these questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title+%5Bggplot2%5D). The [title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/title) tag has this description:

> **DO NOT USE THIS TAG.** In programming languages, title can refer to the title of a figure or the title of an object.

Comment: Do they need to be tagged in any special way? I'm not sure what problem you're trying to solve here.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery The problem is that the question is about titles in ggplot2 in R, and I would like to tag it with [tag:r], [tag:ggplot2] and [tag:title]. But [tag:title] is discouraged (?), so what to use instead?

Comment: Looks like that there's a tag [tag:ggtitle], and that *appears* to be related to ggplot, according to this [page](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-title-main-axis-and-legend-titles). If that is the right tag, then you might want to also [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-tag-wiki/132078) said tag with some guidance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short answer: Use [ggtitle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ggtitle), courtesy of [@Larnu](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2029983/larnu) in a [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405071/tag-questions-about-plot-titles#comment823525_405071) above, which appears to be the specific version of “title” that’s relevant to your usage.

---

Long answer:
I think it’s worth considering the primary purpose of tags here. [Tags are designed to](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) connect experts with questions, by categorizing posts into specific, well-defined groupings based on their content.

Knowing this, when you decide to tag your question with a certain tag, you should consider whether that tag will actually help connect your question to relevant experts. In this case, if a tag is labeled with “*DO NOT USE THIS TAG*,” it’s likely been marked as such because it fails this purpose of bringing experts to relevant content in some way (usually, it seems, by being ambiguous).

Realistically, since no one can become an “expert” in the [title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/title) tag, it’s not going to be very useful to your question, since it won’t bring anyone with unique expertise to provide an answer.

Lucky for you though, a specific tag appears to exist in this instance, [ggtitle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ggtitle), which you should definitely use instead. Even if there wasn’t a more specific equivalent, however, you probably still shouldn’t use this tag, because it won’t *really* be helping your question out anyway.